# Sharing Microsoft Teams Shift across organization

Tags: office365, microsoft-teams, shift

I created a shift for my team using Microsoft Corp Shift app on Teams.

It works great within a people added to shift but how can I share it with everyone in my organization/team?

Answer (score 1):

You should set a policy to assign to the user members of the group.

Get the GroupObjectId of the particular group:

```
$group = Get-AzureADGroup -SearchString "Contoso Firstline Team"
```

Get the members of the specified group:

```
$members = Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $group.ObjectId -All $true | Where-Object {$_.ObjectType -eq "User"}
```

More detail information:

[Manage the Shifts app for your organization in Microsoft Teams](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/expand-teams-across-your-org/shifts/manage-the-shifts-app-for-your-organization-in-teams)

Comment: Thanks but not sure how this will help me.
I have no problem assigning dozen of people within shift.

What I cannot find is how can I make it visible to others